# Evaluate different layout algorithms / interaction with graphs

Tags: algorithm, graph, visualization, data-visualization

I have to write a report on the following question:

Evaluate different layout algorithms / interaction with graphs

Where can I find useful resource to understand graph layout algorithms?

I have no experience in graph programming or visualisation, so resources starting from basics would be very helpful.

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to check the extensive documentation of the [igraph](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/) software, which has some description of its internal [layout generators](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/html/igraph-Layout.html). There are also nice illustrations on [aiSee](http://www.aisee.com/) website.

For more academic reference, I would suggest browsing the following tutorials: [Graph Drawing Tutorial](http://www.cs.brown.edu/~rt/papers/gd-tutorial/gd-constraints.pdf) (106 pages) or [Graph and Network Visualization](http://weblectures.cc.gatech.edu/powerpoints/stasko_weblectures/graph.pdf) (69 pages).

Another useful resource: [Handbook of Graph Drawing and Visualization](http://www.cs.brown.edu/~rt/gdhandbook/) (26 chapters, available as PDF).

Answer (score 3):

The [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) project contain lots of different approaches and links to [several references](http://www.graphviz.org/Theory.php).